# No newline after output (cin)

Tags: c++, cin

I am trying to output a string that I have previously read using `cin>>input` until **EOF**. The problem that I am facing is that after I output the string there is no new line when asking for the next string. I already tried using `getline()`, but the problem was that it was **not skipping whitespaces**. Any clues ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    string input;
    while (cin>>input)
    {
        cout<<input;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example :

> Input:test test
>
> Output: test test
>
> Input:test test...  (Previous input remains in stdin)

Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate, but I could not find anything similar.

Comment: The new line character (`\n`) is not part of the `input`. You need to append it yourself.

Comment: I get your point, but wouldn't that add a new line for each string I input? For example if the string is test test, 
test \n
test \n will be the output

Comment: Yes. In that case, you'd probably want to use `getline`, and remove the whitespaces yourself.

Comment: `std::getline` and `std::`stringstream` work well together. See [Option 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301). Since all streams present a shared interface, this trick will work for `cin` just like it does a file.